# VBA Opening multiple workbooks defined by the user with filter restriction

Tags: vba

I am new to VBA programming and there are three points i would like to do

1, I would like to restrict file type are `".xls", ".xlsx" or ".csv"` 
2, I would record the File Name and File path i have selected 
3, I have error if MultiSelect:=True instead of False

Here is my code that i have at the moment

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim FPath As Variant
    Dim FName As Variant


    FPath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
            FileFilter:="Excel Workbooks, *.xl*", _  #*.xl* | *.csv*
            Title:="Choose a Workbook to Open,", _
            MultiSelect:=True)                      #I think we need to set TRUE

    FName = Dir(FPath, vbDirectory)                  # i want to get rid of .csv/ .xls/ .xlsx

    Range("A1").Value = FName

    If FName <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FPath
    End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: firstly, i want to set the filter that able to read in .xls/.xlsx/.csv only

secondly, i want to show the filename only without the .xls/.xlsx/.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try like this

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim FName() As Variant

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
            FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx; *.csv), *.xls", _
            Title:="Choose a Workbook to Open,", _
            MultiSelect:=True)

    If UBound(FName) > 0 Then
        Dim vFile As Variant
        For Each vFile In FName
            MsgBox getPath(vFile)
            MsgBox getFileName(vFile)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=vFile
        Next
     End If
End Sub

Private Function getPath$(f)
    getPath = Left(f, InStrRev(f, "\", -1, 1))
End Function

Private Function getFileName$(f)
    Dim wExt$
    wExt = Mid(f, Len(getPath(f)) + 1, Len(f) - Len(getPath(f)))
    getFileName = Mid(wExt, 1, InStrRev(wExt, ".", -1, 1) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: It seems that there is problem if i change multiselect to True

Comment: @user If you change it to `True`, `FName` returns an array instead so you will need to handle that.

Comment: then i should change FName as Array instead of Variant?